Transferring to math Ph.D. program?
I am currently a second-year Ph.D. student in CS at a U.S. university. Previously I have completed 30+ credits from the math department as an undergrad and during my Ph.D. years I have 3 math classes taken in the graduate level. I am currently thinking about mastering out and applying for a pure math program instead due to mismatch in interest. My current supervisor offers to write a reference letter and I will probably ask one of my undergraduate professor and one of my graduate professor (both are from the courses that I took) to write LoR for me. I wonder:

I heard that despite all the 'we do not care about the background' cliche on the application websites, the committee still has a strong preference for students with a math degree. How can I overcome this shortcoming? What is the evidence that I am a 'well-prepared applicant' (quoted from some application website) despite my background as a CS student?
If I do not haste into application this year, what should I do to enhance my chance of getting into a math program next year? Perhaps co-working with some mathematicians in our institution while staying in my CS program? (I am not sure whether that is even possible)


I don't think you will have a lot of problems transferring within the US. If you have the equivalent of upper division math courses, as it seems, then you should be fine.
But you will probably need to extend the time to the degree. You won't be a "second year" doctoral student most likely. You will probably need additional coursework and will probably need to pass difficult comprehensive exams that the coursework is designed for.
Both the comps and the associated coursework are there to guarantee that a math PhD holder is widely versed in math, though it is no longer possible for an individual to know "all" of math. That boundary passed early in the previous century.
But people with a lot less background than yourself, regularly begin doctoral study in the US.
As for the future, figure out what comps are like in some programs you want to transfer into and do some coursework in those areas. Typical coverage is Analysis, Abstract Algebra, and Topology, though it can vary.

Thanks for the reply! I am aware of the extra work that I need to do for the transfer and I am perfectly fine with it.

"Do not care about background" may be (sort of) true, but you should have certain math courses: real analysis; abstract algebra; differential equations.  In some cases you may (as Buffy said) be admitted, and then allowed to make up the missing courses.
